# Creating Heart shaped progress loader | Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to make an Heart shaped progress loader for a react project. I tried using css. But, it didn't show the progress properly, like it only cover some part of the heart design. Below is the code, which i tried to do that. The progress should start from the bottom and need to reach, if it's 100 percentage. Please check and let me know, how can i achieve that.

Thanks in Advance

```
/***Progress***/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';

 class Progress extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            percentage: 60,
        }
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ProgressBar percentage={this.state.percentage}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Progress

/***Progress bar***/

import React from 'react';
import Filler from './Filler.js';

const ProgressBar = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="ProgressBarH">
            <Filler percentage={props.percentage}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProgressBar;

/***Filler***/

import React from 'react';

const Filler = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className = "filler" style={{width: `${props.percentage}%`}} />
    )
}

export default Filler;

/***css***/
.ProgressBarH {
  position: relative;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 1px solid #ff7777 ;
  background-color:#ff7777;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ProgressBarH:before,
.ProgressBarH:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  content: '';
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
   background-color:#ff7777; 
}

.ProgressBarH:before {
  bottom: -1px;
    left: -8px;
}

.ProgressBarH:after {
  top: -8px;
    right: -1px;
} 

.filler {
  /* background: red; */
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transition: width .2s ease-in;

}
```

Comment: check this out https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-beating-heart-with-pure-css-for-your-valentine-2aeb05e2d36e/

Comment: Hi, I created the heart shape like that only. But, I need to show the progress in the heart shape dynamically. So, now with that design, it only covers the part where the main div locates. It doesn't show on few places, where we used before and after elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to fill the heart from bottom to top in the way that you want to if it's created using pseudo elements.

It is possible with a svg with a `clipPath` though - something like this:

```
const ProgressBar = props => {
  const y = 24 - (24 * props.percentage) / 100;
  return (
    <div className="ProgressBarH">
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="24"
        height="24"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      >
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
            <rect x="0" y={y} width="24" height="24" />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <path
          style={{ fill: "red" }}
          d="M12 4.248c-3.148-5.402-12-3.825-12 2.944 0 4.661 5.571 9.427 12 15.808 6.43-6.381 12-11.147 12-15.808 0-6.792-8.875-8.306-12-2.944z"
          clipPath="url(#cut-off-bottom)"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Quick and dirty sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bird-8g63q

Edited to add black border:

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="26"
    height="26"
    viewBox="0 0 26 26"
  >
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
        <rect x="0" y={y} width="26" height="24" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>

    <path
      style={{ fill: "red" }}
      d="M12 4.248c-3.148-5.402-12-3.825-12 2.944 0 4.661 5.571 9.427 12 15.808 6.43-6.381 12-11.147 12-15.808 0-6.792-8.875-8.306-12-2.944z"
      clipPath="url(#cut-off-bottom)"
    />
    <path
      style={{ stroke: "black", strokeWidth: "2", fill: "none" }}
      d="M12 4.248c-3.148-5.402-12-3.825-12 2.944 0 4.661 5.571 9.427 12 15.808 6.43-6.381 12-11.147 12-15.808 0-6.792-8.875-8.306-12-2.944z"
    />
  </svg>
```

(See [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bird-8g63q))

Comment: Thanks Dude, I needed like this only.

Comment: HI @WillJenkins, How can i apply a border to this heartshape ?

Comment: i.e i.e. when its not loaded, i need an hearttshaped border line with black color. Inside this border only the loader should work. @WillJenkins

Comment: Have updated my answer. It needs a polish but hopefully you get the idea...